# NSImage to NSData as PNG Swift

Tags: swift, macos, png, nsdata, nsimage

I am writing a Mac app based on an iOS app. The code below converts a UIImage to NSData to upload to Parse.com.

I would like to do the same for Mac but I do not seem to be able to convert it to NSData. What should I be doing?

Thanks

```
var image = UIImage(named: "SmudgeInc")

let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

let imageFile = PFFile(name:"image.png", data:imageData)
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the `NSImage` property [TIFFRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSImage/TIFFRepresentati) to convert your `NSImage` to `NSData`:

```
let imageData = yourImage.TIFFRepresentation
```

If you need to save your image data to a PNG file you can use `NSBitmapImageRep(data:)` and `representationUsingType` to create an extension to help you convert `Data` to PNG format:

**Update: Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1**

```
extension NSBitmapImageRep {
    var png: Data? { representation(using: .png, properties: [:]) }
}
extension Data {
    var bitmap: NSBitmapImageRep? { NSBitmapImageRep(data: self) }
}
extension NSImage {
    var png: Data? { tiffRepresentation?.bitmap?.png }
}
```

---

**usage**

```
let picture = NSImage(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!)!

let imageURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .desktopDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("image.png")
if let png = picture.png {
    do {
        try png.write(to: imageURL)
        print("PNG image saved")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432709/saving-nsimage-in-different-formats-locally/46481947#46481947